# How to determine if line intersect simple polygon?

Tags: geometry, intersection

I need to know how to determine fast if line intersects simple polygon.
It should work in O(log n) time, where n is number of polygon's vertexes.
I searched in google, but I didn't find anything useful, maybe I'm blind. ;)
Edit: I'm using C++ but I think language isn't a problem, and it isn't homework, just doing some algorithms training. Geometry is sick. ;)
Oh. I forgot it's only in 2d.
Thanks for future and actual help.

Comment: need more info. what language are you using, what are your objects, etc.  Is this homework?

Comment: Why the O(lon n) time requirement for a "simple polygon"? Anything with that time complexity is going to be slow and complicated for smallish polygons.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a paper who solves this problem really fast:

"Fast MinimumStorage RayTriangle Intersection"

http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~gfx/Courses/2003/ImageSynthesis/papers/Acceleration/Fast%20MinimumStorage%20RayTriangle%20Intersection.pdf

EDIT: It even contains code :)

Comment: the link returns a 403. Try this https://cadxfem.org/inf/Fast%20MinimumStorage%20RayTriangle%20Intersection.pdf